# How to add maven indirect dependency without conflict in multiple version scenario

Tags: spring, maven, spring-integration

The question may sound bit odd, and there is reverse side of question: **how to remove transient dependency ??**

Well I have a current scenario where I am using two different version of spring dependency(core in exact), although not directly but through indirect dependency.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

which is indirectly using `spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE`. But my entire project is using `spring-3.2.3.RELEASE` configuration.

So I have two option either 1.Increase spring framework version as a whole
2. Remove above dependency

If m changing the version, other dependency are breaking. Also I can't further downgrade `spring-integration-core` version in order to get `MessageChannel class`

So please help me, is there any other way to force the indirect dependency without any conflict.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible. The minimal Spring Framework for the Spring Integration 4.0 is exactly 4.0.

Yes, Spring Integration 3.0 is compatible with SF 4.0, but not vise versa.

So, you don't have choice unless upgrade all your dependencies to the SF 4.0.